# React conditional rendering on div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering what would be a way to do conditional rendering the way I am doing it now.
Is there a way to just add the boolean checked isVisible=true onto the div ? and it will only true.

Would it be an issue because the state of the component does get changed after it's been rendered ?

```
import React from "react";

class BeerCard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(props);
    this.state = {
      isVisible: "false",
      isClicked: "not clicked"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      isVisible: "false",
      isClicked: "not clicked"
    });
    if (this.props.beer.ph === 4.4) {
      this.setState({
        isVisible: "true"
      });
    }
  }

  onClicked = e => {
    this.setState({
      isClicked:
        this.state.isClicked === "is clicked" ? "not clicked" : "is clicked"
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="beerlist__item" isVisible="true" onClick={this.onClicked}>
        {this.state.isVisible}
        <h2>{this.props.beer.name}</h2>
        <h3>{this.props.beer.ph}</h3>
        <p>{this.props.beer.tagline}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default BeerCard;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either call a function that returns some JSX-code

```
renderCode() {
  if (this.state.isVisible) {
    return ( <div>HelloWorld....</div>);
  }
  return null
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.renderCode()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Or do it inline

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        this.state.isVisible ? <div>Helloworld...</div> : null
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
if (!visible) return null 
return (
      <div className="beerlist__item" isVisible="true" onClick={this.onClicked}>
        {this.state.isVisible}
        <h2>{this.props.beer.name}</h2>
        <h3>{this.props.beer.ph}</h3>
        <p>{this.props.beer.tagline}</p>
      </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
 render() {
    return (
      <div className="beerlist__item" isVisible="true" onClick={this.onClicked}>
        {this.state.isVisible &&
            <h2>{this.props.beer.name}</h2>
            <h3>{this.props.beer.ph}</h3>
            <p>{this.props.beer.tagline}</p>
        }

      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to write isVisible="true" inside your div tag - you can just do conditional rendering like below -

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="beerlist__item" onClick={this.onClicked}>
        {this.state.isVisible &&
            <h2>{this.props.beer.name}</h2>
            <h3>{this.props.beer.ph}</h3>
            <p>{this.props.beer.tagline}</p>
        }

      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, there's an HTML attribute [`hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) that could help you.
You can set your render return something like this:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="beerlist__item" hidden={!this.state.isVisible} onClick={this.onClicked}>
        {this.state.isVisible}
        <h2>{this.props.beer.name}</h2>
        <h3>{this.props.beer.ph}</h3>
        <p>{this.props.beer.tagline}</p>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Bear in mind that the `React.Node` still exists in the React Virtual DOM and any changes occurred in the state of that component will trigger the `render` method of children React components.

PS. I noticed that in your `componentDidMount` you call `setState` and after that you run another state change if condition is fulfilled.
I want to remind you that `setState` is running asyncronously and you should instead use the callback function that you can define in the [second parameter](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), that will get executed when state effectively changes.